# How to set a mysql timeout for the session or mysql event

Tags: mysql

I use my sql event for a simple delete operation.
One day the delete operation triggered dead lock.
I wonder how to set a timeout for the event.

Answer (score 0):

A deadlock occurs immediately because another transaction was changing the table row you where deleting.

You don't need a timeout change, it won't help.

You need to handle the deadlock in your exception in your code. Why is a delete and an insert/modification of the same data occurring? The business reason for this happening will also dictate what needs to occur when this exception occurs.